# understand the terminology for packet forwarding engine in Juniper routers

Tags: juniper, juniper-mx

Is it correct to say that packet forwarding engines for MX960 series are DPC, DPCE, MPC, etc? And all those DPC, DPCE, etc cards actually include one or more packet forwarding engines? So in similar fashion CFEB is the packet forwarding engine for M10i and it contains actually one or more FPCs?

Comment: This can be a pretty big subject depending on the hardware you're using, take a look at this and feel free to update your question if anything still isn't clear.

http://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB23065

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is correct to say that each of that card, DPC,DPCe and MPC provides packet forwarding engines. Everyone of this card uses this mechanism to forwarding.

Several types of DPCs are available. Each DPC includes either two or four Packet Forwarding Engines. Each Packet Forwarding Engine enables a throughput of 10 Gbps.

```
(http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/en_US/release-independent/junos/topics/concept/mx960-description.html)
```

Comment: I see. However, when someone talks about a PFE of Juniper router, then is it correct to think of PFE as the ASIC's(for example Trio chipset) on FEB(DPC, CFEB, SSB, etc), the FEB itself or the whole PIC+FPC+FEB package?

Comment: In fact, the PPFC are implemented in ASICs, physically located on the FPCs and the PICs. You can see more info here: http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/en_US/release-independent/junos/topics/concept/packet-forwarding-engine-t320-t640-t1600-architecture.html